# Есть ли возможность отключить отрицательные индексы в Python

Tags: python, list

Есть ли возможность, чтобы в случае, если индекс списка отрицателен, то просто ничего не делать?

Comment: сделать проверку индекса перед использованием? либо взять модуль )

Comment: Как вариант, я просто думал, что есть какой-нибудь встроенный метод для этого.

Comment: Скорее всего я думаю, что нету. [Похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41556230/is-it-possible-to-disable-negative-indexing?rq=1) Либо [еще один пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410615/python-lists-arrays-disable-negative-indexing-wrap-around-in-slices/13410878), создать класс и переопределить метод, но выгляд конечно будет не очень.

Answer (score 1):

Читаем элементарный тюториал по Python и с удивлением обнаруживаем, что отрицательный индекс в этом языке очень много чего значит. Это не ошибка, как например в С++. И совсем не то же самое, что превышение максимального индекса (явная ошибка).  На самом деле это сообщение интерпретатору о том, что отсчет надо вести не от начала списка, а наоборот, с конца.  Если вас это чем-то не устраивает, то перед тем как использовать индекс, надо делать проверку, ну например:

```
if i>=0 :
    list[i]
else:
    pass
```